# How to make multiple lambda functions with a function?

Tags: python, lambda

I want to make multiple lambda functions with different parameters and bind them to a dictionary.

```
dic_funcs = {}

dates = ['2018', '2019', '2020']

idx = ['0', '1', '2']

def printt(text):
    print(text)


for d in dates:
    for i in idx:

        #print(d, i)

        dic_funcs[d + '_' + i] = lambda:printt(d + '_' + i)


for key, item in dic_funcs.items():
    print(key)
    item()      
    print('-----')
```

I thought that each key and the result of the corresponding value(lambda function) would be the same, but they are not.

```
2018_0
2020_2
-----
2018_1
2020_2
-----
2018_2
2020_2
-----
2019_0
2020_2
-----
2019_1
2020_2
-----
2019_2
2020_2
-----
2020_0
2020_2
-----
2020_1
2020_2
-----
2020_2
2020_2
-----
```

I think I bound the same date and index number each time. What could be the problem? I'd appreciate it if I could get some help with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your lambda expression you've got an `i` which is from your loop through `idx`, and a `d` which is from your loop through `dates`. The both these values in your lambda expression aren't evaluated at function definition but rather when the function is called, so each time you're doing `print(d + '_' + i)`, the function just looks up the current value of `d` and `i`, which is just the value of the last thing in `for d in dates` and `for i in idx`, which is why you're getting the same value each time.

You can work around this with a hack like:

```
dic_funcs[d + '_' + i] = lambda a=i, b=d:printt(b + '_' + a)
```

Which gives you your intended behavior

Comment: Thank you for your detailed explanation! That helped me a lot!